# How to get Google Play to suggest my app?

Tags: google-play

I uploaded a game to Play and obviously it isn't the very first suggestion on the list. I uploaded it 3 days ago.

As somehow new games do get played, I assume people start to know about them.

I would like to ask that how does Play start suggesting an app? Is it by download count/download frequency? Or does it show new apps by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google won't release the exact algorithm used for getting featured or getting listed on the store front, probably because they want to minimize the amount people try game the system.

Having said that it is safe to assume that number of downloads and ratings are key to get featured.

At Google I/O there was a talk on this a few years ago: https://youtu.be/5Od2SuL2igA